# Struts2: issue with loading the resource file

Tags: java, struts2, jboss

I encountered the problem of loading resource file. I have two applications (1 ear with 1 war inside + 1 separate war). Both apps have struts.xml and both have own resource files. 
I use `struts.custom.i18n.resources` to load the resources.
When I url to first app, resource file loads fine. However second app does not load its own resource file. Server (JBOSS) gets lots of warnings: The default value expression ... was evaluated and did not match a property. 
If I change `struts.devMode` to true then everything works fine. 
Please advise.